# pgfplot polaraxis y tick labels overlapping

Tags: pgfplots, axis, polar

I am just trying to create a polar axis plot with yticks being 0.5,0.75,...2.5. However, when I go through with it using:

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin= 0.8in, top= 0.8in, bottom= 0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
                    xmin=0,%
                    xmax=360,%
                    ymin=0.5,%
                    ymax=2.5,%
                    xticklabels={},
                    ytick distance=0.25,
                    %yticklabel={500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000, 2250, 2500},
                    axis lines*=none,%
                    axis line style = {draw=white,line width=0.0001pt},
                    ]
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My axis labels are all overlapping and it looks like this[image]

Is there anyway maybe I can increase the plot size without changing the size of the label, or perhaps alternate them such that they are all readable?

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! What about rotating the labels and/or decrease the font size?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
                    xmin=0,%
                    xmax=360,%
                    ymin=0.5,%
                    ymax=2.5,%
                    xticklabels={},
                    ytick distance=0.25,
                    %yticklabel={500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000, 2250, 2500},
                    y tick label style={font=\footnotesize, rotate=90},
                    axis lines*=none,%
                    axis line style = {draw=white,line width=0.0001pt},
                    ]
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you so much!